# can I get rid of the color glow

Tags: rendering

I have this orange glow in my render and I want to get rid. of that and just keep the orange bals without the glow how can I do this? (you can see the glow in the middle of the picture) [image]

Comment: are you using cycle? can you show us the nodes you used?

Comment: I am maybe not understanding right what you ask but I don't tink I used nodes the orange is just a color I rendered this whit 2000samples and just the basic settings I changed nothing

Comment: try to go in the Properties panel > Object > Visibility, disable Diffuse

Comment: thankyouu soo soo much its fixed THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Go in the *Properties panel > Object > Visibility*, disable *Diffuse*.